# Referring to new features in the next version of Ubuntu

Tags: discussion

In [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/214980/109543), the person is unable to install a package. I believe this is due to the package only being [available for the amd64 build](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/+source/gnome-boxes) of Ubuntu. However, [according to Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/+source/gnome-boxes), it will be available for the 32 bit version as well in Ubuntu 13.04.

I know questions about the next version of Ubuntu are considered off-topic, but would it be allowable or even a good idea to mention that this package will be available in Ubuntu 13.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it would. Just not in an answer, since it doesn't actually answer the question. I think a comment would be more appropriate.

Comments are there for important information that is beside the point and doesn't answer the question.

Although if you wanted to add an answer explaining that you think this is program only works on 64 bit Ubuntu and why you think that, it would also be appropriate to add a note at the bottom of your answer saying this package would be available in 13.04.

Comment: By "comment at the bottom of your answer", do you mean as an actual comment, or part of the answer itself?

Comment: Oh,  sorry,  I meant at the bottom of the answer,  but _in_ the answer.   I'll try to clarify the answer.