# Beta/Alpha/Development versions are said not being covered - so Ubuntu Touch questions are not welcome?

Tags: discussion

I just read the comment "Ubuntu Phones is in development, so it is off-topic here at Ask Ubuntu. We do not support Beta/Alpha/Development versions."

Are questions welcome regarding Ubuntu Touch only after it has been introduced officially?

I have seen a few questions referrring to this topic:

[Should questions about Nexus 7 be off-topic?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5308/should-questions-about-nexus-7-be-off-topic)

[Referring to new features in the next version of Ubuntu](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5957/referring-to-new-features-in-the-next-version-of-ubuntu)

but I would like to see an answer how to handle it from the persons perspective who is asking.

Comment: The first link you post seems to answer your question!

Comment: How are we supposed to answer them when Ubuntu Touch is still in development and only Canonical knows what the plans are for the OS, what hardware will be supported, etc?

Comment: I also had this question in mind when the Touch Preview got out and we started receiving questions about it. See this meta question - [When are questions about "ubuntu+1" appropriate?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/871/114818). According to this, not all the questions about Ubuntu+1 are off-topic :-)

Comment: @JorgeCastro: so We treat Ubuntu Touch like any other productive product? Is that what you want to say? Only bug reports and speculative questions are inappropriate as they would be as well for all other tags/products? Thanks for a clarifying yes - or a different precise statement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### It is an exception

Ubuntu touch is a new project and both community and Canonical have high interest in it. We don't allow normal alpha/beta release questions because of their low quality and too localised nature.

But in the case of Ubuntu touch, most of the questions have quality and Canonical devs are ready to maintain the tag. The only problem is, only Canonical employees can answer some of the questions.

Comment: this clarifies the situation!

Comment: @jokerdino : Thanks :)

Answer (score 12):

- [Should questions about Nexus 7 be off-topic?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5308/should-questions-about-nexus-7-be-off-topic)

This question was when Ubuntu had only announced the Nexus 7 work. However since then there's been a bunch of work in this area it's been broadly expanded to [ubuntu-touch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-touch).

They're about a project that's pretty much brand new, and in progress, the difference between this and normal alpha/beta questions is that the developers working on Ubuntu Touch are curating the tag and ensuring it's high quality, we don't allow alpha/beta questions because most of them are just bug reports anyway and they'd just be noise.

Comment: The project should be considered on-topic here, as the project has matured a bunch since its announcement, in my opinion.